# Method/Symbol cannot be resolved doesn't highlight in Eclipse C

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, undefined-symbol

My Eclipse for CDT doesn't highlight an error/warning for a new called function that I haven't declared (and defined it before).
For example in my code I call this function haven't declared:

[image: without error warning]

I want to have an error warning like this:

[image: with error warning]

I check the option in Project->Properties-> C/C++ General->Code Analysis and all of the options are already checked.

Anybody know how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

That functionality does not exists yet (CDT mars) (since this
is technically not an error in C).
Bug is open https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484373
to add this for code analysis.
And it is close to being submitted... I will update this post if I push
this fix for neon (next version).